# Injectivity of integral operators

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-inequalities

Let $K:L^2[0,1]^{d_1}\to L^2[0,1]^{d_2}$ be integral operator
$$(Kf)(y) = \int f(x)k(x,y)d x.$$
If $d_1>d_2$ is it possible for $K$ to be injective?, e.g. let's take $d_1=2,d_2=1$.

More generally, does the injectivity of $K$ impose any restrictions on $d_1,d_2$.

Comment: Is there any information on $k(x,y)$? For instance, in the trivial case when $k(x,y)$ does not depend on $y$ and vanishes for all $x \in (0,0.5)$, then $Kf(y) =0 \ \forall y$ for some non-zero function $f$, so the operator is not injective.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any conditions. I need an example of injective $K$ when $d_1>d_2$ (or at least in knowing whether this is possible). I'm not interested in counterexamples.

Comment: Well, what are your thoughts on the question so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $d_1=2$, $d_2=1$. I couldn't immediately find a "trivial" example, but here is one. Let $\{g_n\}_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]^2$. Let $\{E_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ by intervals, and 
$$
k(x,y)=\sum_n g_n(x)\,1_n(y).
$$

For $y\in E_m$,
\begin{align}
Kf(y)
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x_1,x_2)\,g_m(x_1,x_2)\,dx_1\,dx_2.
\end{align}

If $Kf=0$ we have, for all $m$, 
$$\tag1
0=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x_1,x_2)\,g_m(x_1,x_2)\,dx_1\,dx_2,\ \ \ \ \ \ m\in\mathbb N.
$$
As $\{g_m\}$ is total, this implies that $f=0$, and so $K$ is injective.

Comment: Great question and answer!  However, for completeness, if $d_2 = 0$ and $d_1 > 0$, then $K$ can never be injective.  Indeed for $d_2 = 0$, $Kf = \int k(x)f(x)dx$ becomes the scalar product of $k$ and $f$ and there is never a $k\neq 0$ that would always be orthogonal to every $f$.  This special case may sound trivial but I feel it emphasizes a proper parameter dependence must exist within the kernel to have a shot at any injectiveness.